# Can't catch exception from jdbcQueryObject

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, try-catch

I'm trying obtain a String from query with jdbcQueryObject but sometimes, this query don't obtain anything because not exists in my bd. For this reason, I want to catch this exception but I can't get it. I have try with this:

```
try {
    StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer();
    query.append("SELECT DES_VALOR_A FROM ").append(esquema).append(".TKACSVLT WHERE COD_ID_LST = (SELECT COD_ID_LST FROM ")
         .append(esquema).append(".TKACSLST WHERE DES_NOMB_LST LIKE 'Fecha cambio ponderacion')");
                    
    fechaPonderacionBD = jdbcQueryObject(new ParameterizedRowMapper<String>() {
        public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException, DataAccessException  {
            return rs.next() ? rs.getString("DES_VALOR_A") : null;
            }
        }, query.toString(), new Object[]{});
                    
    if(fechaPonderacionBD != null)
        fechaPonderacion = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(fechaPonderacionBD);
                    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getLog().error("[BD - ERROR] Error en obtener fecha limite ponderacion", e);
    }
```

But I obtain this error:
**org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0**

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: that means that your code is written in such a way, that the query you execute must return exactly one record from the database, but it doesn't find any.

Comment: YOur rowmapper is the fault, remove the `rs.next` part that is handled by Spring.